# How to update image on edit view grails?

Tags: image, grails, updates

on class domain:

```
class Employee {

    String name
    ...
    ...
    byte[] picture
    static constraints = {
        name()
        .....
        picture (nullable:true, maxSize: 1048576 /* 16K */)
    }
}
```

on form view:

```
<div id="preview" class="thumbnail">
    <a href="#" id="file-select" class="btn btn-default">Choose File</a>
    <img class="img-circle" alt="User Image" style="width:100%;"
         src="${employeeInstance?.picture? 
         createLink(controller:'employee', action:'image',
         id:employeeInstance.id):assetPath(src: 'user-default.png')}"/>
</div>
<input type="file" id="picture" name="picture" class="form-control" />
<span class="alert alert-info" id="file-info">No file yet</span>
```

on controller:

```
def image() {
    def avatarUser = Employee.get(params.id)
    if (!avatarUser || !avatarUser.picture){//|| !avatarUser.avatarType) {
        response.sendError(404)
        return
    }
    response.contentType = "image/jpeg"//avatarUser.avatarType
    response.contentLength = avatarUser.picture.size()
    OutputStream out = response.outputStream
    out.write(avatarUser.picture)
    out.close()
}

protected void notFound() {
    request.withFormat {
        form multipartForm {
            flash.message = message(code: 'default.not.found.message', args: [message(code: 'employee.label', default: 'Employee'), params.id])
            redirect action: "index", method: "GET"
        }
    }
}
```

I upload an image and present it on Edit view , but at time to update does not preserve the image even when I don't change the picture.

Comment: what does your update method look like?

Answer (score 1):

Without the update method is hard to know how you are handling the update. But without knowing much, when you present the image, I suppose you put it in an `<img>` tag, and then if the user updates information, without changing the image, all the data is being sent in the `params` but in this case, `avatarUser.picture` would be `null` since there wont be a field that matches that parameter being sent from the form you presented to the user. Maybe if you had a field that you took in the controller as the image sent from the form that had the image bytes encoded as base64 in the form could be a solution, not a very clean one but it would work. The problem is I don't know much of the rest of your implementation but for what I read I think it might work:
in your update view a hidden tag with the image encoded in base 64:

```
<input type="hidden" name="name-you-expect-in-update-controller" value="${Employee.picture.encodeBase64().toString()}" />
```

That way you would get in your update controller a parameter with a base64 encoded string that you would then decode as follows:

```
byte[] image= encodedImage.decodeBase64()
```

and then use it with your method `image()` as you are doing right now.

Hope I took the track you wanted to solve the problem!